# How can I efficiently respond to ingame target selection events?

Tags: events, lua, world-of-warcraft

*I come from a C#/Java background and have never touched Lua before.*

I want the addon to show a message (default message window) that prints out the class of the target whenever I click on and target another player, and ONLY when I target a player.  I have two files, **SpeccySpecs.lua** (contains the functions needed to handle the event) and **SpeccySpecs.xml** (contains the frame to run the function).  Whenever I run the addon ingame, I am getting nil errors because my **Core.lua** file is returning nil when requiring the .xml file and my .xml file returns a nil from the `OnTarget()` function in **SpeccySpecs.lua**.

I have tried to solve this in multiple ways, one of which was by creating a local table and requiring it in **Core.lua**, where I'd eventually call the function inside the table, but it also returned nil.  I've been using
sites such as:

https://wowpedia.fandom.com/wiki/Events

https://wowwiki-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Event_API

https://www.lua.org/

But what I've tried simply hasn't worked, and I assume I'm forgetting something small in the Lua code.

*SpeccySpecs.lua*

```
local function getPlayerClass()
    local playerClassName = nil;
    local playerClassFilename = nil;
    local playerClassId = nil;

    if UnitClass("target") ~= nil
    then
        playerClassName, playerClassFilename, playerClassId = UnitClass("target");
        if playerClassName == 1 -- Warrior
        then message ("It's a warrior")
        elseif playerClassId == 2 -- Paladin
        then message ("It's a paladin")
        elseif playerClassId == 3 -- Hunter
        then message ("It's a hunter")
        elseif playerClassId == 4 -- Rogue
        then message ("It's a rogue")
     elseif playerClassId == 5 -- Priest
        then message ("It's a priest")
        elseif playerClassId == 6 -- Death Knight
        then message ("It's a death knight")
        elseif playerClassId == 7 -- Shaman
        then message ("It's a shaman")
        elseif playerClassId == 8 -- Mage
        then message ("It's a mage")
        elseif playerClassId == 9 -- Warlock
        then message ("It's a warlock")
        elseif playerClassId == 10 -- Monk
        then message ("It's a monk")
        elseif playerClassId == 11 -- Druid
        then message ("It's a druid")
        elseif playerClassId == 12 -- Demon Hunter
        then message ("It's a demon hunter")
        else message ("That class does not exist")
        end
    else message ("Please target a player")
    end
end

function OnTarget(self, event, ...)
    print(event)
    return getPlayerClass()
end
```

*SpeccySpecs.xml*

```
<UI>
    <Script file="SpeccySpecs.lua"/>
    <Frame name="SpeccyFrame">
        <Scripts>
            <OnEvent function="OnTarget"/>
        </Scripts>
    </Frame>
</UI>
```

*Core.lua*

```
PlayerClassFrame = require "SpeccySpecs.xml";
return PlayerClassFrame
```

Thanks in advance for the help, everyone.

Comment: what's require doing in that WoW API? in vanilla Lua requiring a xml file would cause errors

Comment: @piglet wow uses xml files for the UI. That basic setup he has is correct.

Comment: @piglet I missed the require part earlier.

Yes, you don't need the require, but the xml looks file. The loading of the xml should start in the wow .toc file. I added a section about that to my answer.

Comment: I saw that the require was not needed in Celess' answer.  I was not aware that WoW was importing things behind the scenes, and that all of my "imports" would be strictly through the TOC file.  Thank you for the explanations everyone, a great read to get me started in this journey.  I am not able to upvote answers due to not being rank 15 on the site yet, but both of your answers helped me a lot.

Comment: @chunky great!  good luck. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goes like this:

make frame (yours is in xml) > OnLoad event handler > register for events > event fired > handle events

**1) You don't need the require or the core.lua:**

WoW has its own explicit ordered loading process that uses toc files and includes in xml.

Your toc file probably looks like:

```
# some stuff    

MyAddon.xml
```

Then your MyAddon.xml loads:

```
<UI>
    <Script file="MyAddon.lua"/>
    <Frame name="MyAddonFrame">
```

Which then loads the .lua file first, so that all the things in the .lua file are available to be referenced as the frame xml loads.

**2) You are missing registering for a specific event:**

For example:

```
<OnLoad> self:RegisterEvent("PLAYER_ENTERING_WORLD") </OnLoad>
```

So that you end up with something like:

```
<OnLoad> self:RegisterEvent("PLAYER_ENTERING_WORLD") </OnLoad>
<OnEvent> print("Event name " .. event) </OnEvent>
```

You need to go find a specific event that deals with when something is targeted that comes as close as possible to fitting what you need.

**3) You need to pass the telemetry from the event to the handler function:**

```
<OnEvent> MyAddon:OnEvent(self, event, ...) </OnEvent>
```

The self is the current frame, event is given to you hind the scenes as OnEvent here just becomes compiled into a regular Lua function and gets event passed to it, and ... is a Lua type of list used for unnamed parameters, which you can break out into Lua variables later.

**4) You need a repeatable way to expose your Lua code across files**

This needs to be in a way that does not clash with WoW or other addons.

```
MyAddon = {}
```

Is one way. This makes a single Lua table with a global unique name that you can stick functions in so they can be found elsewhere outside that one file.

Anything in WoW that is not 'local' goes into a single environment Lua global name space across all addons and wow.

**5) You need to accept the parameters for telemetry from the event:**

And process the telemetry to eek out what you more specifically need

```
function MyAddon:OnEvent(frame, event, ...)
    if event == "SOME_EVENT_NAME" then
        local _, name = ...
        if is this some player then
            MyAddon:SomePlayerDidSomething(name)
        end
    elseif event == "SOME_EVENT_NAME" then
    end
end
```

This should get you started for the basic addon process.

---

After all that is working, then you need a way to make the business end more data driven, which will in theory make it more code-size and speed efficient.

**6) Add a table to lookup strings for ids:**

```
MyAddon.classNames = {
    [1] = "warrior",
    [2] = "paladin",
    [3] = "hunter",
}
```

See https://www.lua.org/pil/3.6.html

Which will allow you to construct code more like this:

```
local className = self.classNames[playerClassId]
if className then
    message("It's a " .. className .. ".")
end
```

This should get you started overall. It's hard to find the right resource often to get you off the ground at the very beginning. You got pretty far.

Answer (score 1):

- You don't necessarily need an XML file, it can all be done in Lua. Also, `require()` does not exist in the WoW environment, that's handled by listing your files in the [TOC](https://wowpedia.fandom.com/wiki/TOC_format)
- The page you linked has the [PLAYER_TARGET_CHANGED](https://wowpedia.fandom.com/wiki/PLAYER_TARGET_CHANGED) event. You can check if a unit is player with [UnitIsPlayer()](https://wowpedia.fandom.com/wiki/API_UnitIsPlayer)

Your code would look something like this:

**SpeccySpecs.toc**

```
## Interface: 90105
## Version: 1.0.0
## Title: SpeccySpecs
## Notes: Some Description
## Author: YourName

SpeccySpecs.lua
```

**SpeccySpecs.lua**

```lua
local classes = {
    [1] = "warrior",
    [2] = "paladin",
    [3] = "hunter",
    [4] = "rogue",
    [5] = "priest",
    [6] = "death knight",
    [7] = "shaman",
    [8] = "mage",
    [9] = "warlock",
    [10] = "monk",
    [11] = "druid",
    [12] = "demon hunter",
}

local function getPlayerClass(unit)
    if UnitExists(unit) then
        local text
        if UnitIsPlayer(unit) then
            local _, _, classId = UnitClass(unit)
            local name = classes[classId]
            if name then
                text = "It's a "..name
            else
                text = "That class does not exist"
            end
        else
            text = "Please target a player"
        end
        message(text)
    end
end

local function OnEvent(self, event)
    getPlayerClass("target")
end

local f = CreateFrame("Frame")
f:RegisterEvent("PLAYER_TARGET_CHANGED")
f:SetScript("OnEvent", OnEvent)
```

Or as a minimal example:

```lua
local f = CreateFrame("Frame")
f:RegisterEvent("PLAYER_TARGET_CHANGED")
f:SetScript("OnEvent", function(self, event)
    if UnitIsPlayer("target") then
        print("It's a "..UnitClass("target"))
    end
end)
```